# Does anyone have suggestions/tips about presenting GitHub sample code to potential employers?

Tags: software-industry, resume, developer, portfolio

I am an ASP.NET Developer with around 6-7 years of ASP.NET development experience.  I do place sample code on the github website, and then mention the url to my github account's sample code.  However, my worry is that my sample code is too big.  Recently, I uploaded a sample ASP.NET application that used AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC.

1) Does anyone have any suggestions/tips about putting up sample code on GitHub in such a way that it does Not overwhelm recruiters/hiring managers/customers/clients by being too big?

2) Could someone please suggest how I should mention my github account's url on my resume so that it will lead potential employers to view my sample code?

Comment: Good question, I have wondered about that as well, I once saw a CV with a github link on it and thought 'wtf is github' and chucked it in the bin, but people here talk about it quite a bit.

Comment: I mention github by adding it to the contact details section in the format `github://username`. I just assume afterwards that anyone reading it also has the knowledge to know what to do with that. In the "Projects" section I talk about some of the projects on there specifically. In fact, looks like dropbox is smart enough to actually turn that into a working url: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dg062k43nvxqjzi/Resume.pdf#

Comment: You can create 'Github pages' pages for the projects you want to direct employers to that break down the project into pieces and direct people on where to look.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't do anything different from what you're doing now. Just mention that your code is on GitHub and add the URL to your profile, https://github.com/yourname. Then let them do the rest.

A large code base means that you've been coding a lot, which is good. Let the technical hiring manager decide which part of your code they want to read. Usually a small sample will suffice to evaluate your skills as a programmer.

Answer (score 3):

If someone is hiring and they place a lot of value on your code portfolio, they will spend more time reviewing it and less time on the tasks others rely on (e.g. trivia questions, what-if scenarios, code tests, etc.). Also, they're more likely to know what they're looking for and where to find it. If I want a backend developer, I'll probably never open your css files.

For those that don't rely on your code samples as much, you can provide a little direction in your cover letter and help them focus on the code that pertains to this position. You will have several interviews. The first-level HR interview, will never look at your code and all you can do is hope they pass the link along in a usable format and not scan it or print it out before sending it to the development team. If they talk about wanting to view your code sample, suggest sending an email with with links to parts you think are relevant. Your ability to do this demonstrates your understanding of your code base and how it is structured.

I have more confidence that the candidate actually wrote this code when they can discuss, make suggestions and guide me through their code. It also shows an appreciation for not wasting other people's time. You either know how to code or you don't, so let's get to it.

Answer (score 2):

I would also say that you should include documentation - github wikis are quick and easy to put together.  A few pages about use cases/requirements, a discussion of the design alternatives you considered, and an explanation of anything that's particularly complicated or obscure.

That helps a lot in assuring the hiring manager and the other technical staff that you actually understand this, and didn't crib it from someone else.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at a candidate’s GitHub account I look less at the quality of their code as I do at the quality of the issues and pull requests they’ve raised. Being able to code makes you a good coder; being able to critically evaluate problems and explain why the code you’ve produced fixes the observed situation makes you a good developer.

Specifically on your CV I wouldn’t put anything beyond a link to your profile, but if you’re putting together a portfolio I’d absolutely link to specific situations where you’ve contributed back to other people’s code in a meaningful way.

Answer (score -5):

Why don't you think out of the box and create a Video CV that explains the projects your are most proud of. You actually showcasing your code enthuastically using video. Within the video you can link off to your github repositories.

Good luck though in the job hunt.